Python Program Skipping User Input and Proceeding Automatically in vs code
My Python program is supposed to wait for input from the user, but instead, it proceeds to take input from the next line of code automatically
my code is
num1 = input()
num2 = input()
print(num1 + num2)

In terminal
num1 = input()
num2 = input()
>>> print(num1 + num2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'num2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'num1'?'

enter image description here
how to resolve this issue.

This seems like an XY problem. How is your program getting run? Do you have a .py file? What is this code supposed to accomplish/why are you calling input() in the terminal? Please [edit] your question to include some of these details.

If you printed out the value of num1, you'd see that it is num2 = input() - the second line fulfilled the input() in the first line of code, rather than being interpreted as a line of code itself.  PAY ATTENTION TO THE PROMPT - you should have noticed that the >>> was missing for that second line!

Hello, I'm not sure what kind of effect you're expecting. Why do you want to run in a terminal? You can save these codes to a .py file. Then run the file in the terminal with the command python yourfile.py. Is the result of this running that way what you were expecting?

I assume from what I'm seeing in the editor area (three lines selected) and terminal view (second line of selected code was taken as input line for the first selected line's input() call) that you selected those lines in the editor and then did something to either directly or indirectly invoke the Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal. I can repro with the following code:
foo = input("give me an input")
print("hello world!")
print(foo)

which results in the following when running the Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal command:
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo = input("give me an input")
give me an inputprint("hello world!")
>>> print(foo)
print("hello world!")
>>> 

I suggest you start by reading up on what a REPL is (the Python interpreter can be invoked as one in "interactive mode").
Roughly speaking (I'm not a Python or terminal/shell expert, so I may have gotten details wrong), the Python interpreter in interpreter mode goes line by line (from an input such as the standard input stream) and executes each line. In the above example, the first line is foo = input(...). This tells the interpreter to take the next line and return it from the call to the input() function. The next line is print("hello world!"), which you intend to be instructions for the interpreter, but instead it gets taken as input to input(). Then the Python interpreter takes the next line and runs it- print(foo). I don't think I have the details or explanation down exactly- ex. whether the standard input stream is involved here- since if I put this code in a file and then run python3 < file.py, I get the following:
give me an inputTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

If anyone else wants to dig deeper, see the implementation of python.execSelectionInTerminal in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/34dac5c8741af2cf1f140e74706ae9304051ae8d/src/client/terminals/codeExecution/codeExecutionManager.ts#L74. I got stuck trying to track it down at a service boundary.
Anyhow, really what you want to do is run the file. You can do that with the Python: Run Python File in Terminal command, which should be conveniently bound to the play button in the top right action button bar.

As you learn to develop Python programs, you will realize that the language relies heavily on structure and formatting of the lines of code, which in doing a quick cursive review seems to indicate it would probably be very beneficial for you to search out and review some fundamental Python tutorials to see some of the formatting standards, such as when and where to place lines of code on separate lines.
In testing out your initial code as such:
num1 = input() num2 = input()

print(num1 + num2)

resulted in a syntax error at the terminal.
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Gimme$ python3 Gimme.py 
  File "/home/craig/Python_Programs/Gimme/Gimme.py", line 1
    num1 = input() num2 = input()
                   ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

That is, the language was complaining that it did not know how to handle the two prompts on the same line.
Doing a really simple bit of refactoring by placing the input prompts on separate lines did provide for the entry of two values.
num1 = input() 
num2 = input()

print(num1 + num2)

craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Gimme$ python3 Gimme.py 
33
145
33145

So to reiterate, the main takeaway would be to hunt out and review Python tutorial literature, either in a manual and/or online.

line1: num1 = input()
line2: num2 = input()
line3: print(num1 + num2)
